# I am trying to convert .bagfile to .pcd in ros kinetic

Tags: pcl, ros-kinetic, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to convert .bagfile to .pcd in ros kinetic using

```
rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd run1_2013-05-28-10-41-40_0.bag /velodyne_packets ./pointclouds
```

but the pcd file is not showing in the directory folder!! what should be the solution for this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283358/i-am-trying-to-convert-.bagfile-to-.pcd-in-ros-kinetic/) by [prash322](https://answers.ros.org/users/33807/prash322/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Command must have printed some kind of output. Generally speaking when asking questions please provide system output as much as possible.

Make sure the bag file contains the right topics with non-zero count. In your case, inspect using rosbag's [commandline tools](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#rosbag_info) by the following, the PCL topic you want to convert is contained (the following example is using a different message as you haven't provided enough info so that I have no idea what message it should be):

```
rosbag info run1_2013-05-28-10-41-40_0.bag
:
topics:      /velodyne_packets   119 msgs @ 100.0 Hz : geometry_msgs/Point
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prash322](https://answers.ros.org/users/33807/prash322/) on 2018-02-24**:
sorry that i didn't added any system output. I have used the command rosbag info run1_2013-05-28-10-41-40_0.bag already and the package which i want to convert to pcd is available. pointcloud folder is creating but couldn't find the pcd file in the folder.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-02-25**:
Please update your original question post to add the command line output. You still haven't provided enough info so that it's difficult to help you in general.